# Grant copy artIfact permission in multi-branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have the following setup:

A Jenkins multi-branch pipeline job configured through `Jenkinsfile`. After successful checkout and build, the artifact is archived and a downstream job is triggered to deploy the generated artifact.

For the second job to be able to copy the artefact through the `[$class: 'CopyArtifact'...` step, it needs copy permissions.

So the question is, how do I grant those permissions through the `Jenkinsfile` of the upstream job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Scripted Pipeline Syntax, this works:

```
  properties([[$class: 'CopyArtifactPermissionProperty', projectNames: 'Other Project Name'], [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false], pipelineTriggers([])])
```

Comment: is there a way to use wildcards - or allow all other build to access ?

Answer (score 9):

In declarative pipelines, this is the preferred syntax:

```
options {
    copyArtifactPermission('my-downstream-project');
}
```

Available from version 1.41 of [Copy Artifact](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact).