# Jenkins copyArtifact permission

Tags: jenkins

I have tried to use the Copy Artifact Plugin in a Jenkinsfile as this:

```
copyArtifacts(projectName: 'myProject', selector: lastSuccessful(), filter: '*.png*', target: 'Figures');
```

The code is working but I also need to the the permission of 'myProject' to use the plugin. Via Jenkins it's a tic-box like this:

[image]

I can only check the ticbox if I don't use a Jenkins file in the Jenkins job.

Question: How can I set the permission in the jenkins file directly instead of using the ticbox?

Comment: Do you have access to the machine where this is built?

Comment: Yes I have access to the computer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grant copy artIfact permission in multi-branch pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771722/grant-copy-artifact-permission-in-multi-branch-pipeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    options {
        copyArtifactPermission('job1,job2,...');
    }
    stages{...}
}
```